# Closed-form formula for a multivariate polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

Counting certain walks in threshold graphs, I came upon the following independent problem.
Assume that $x_1,\dots,x_a$ are independent variables and for $k\geq 2$ let
$$
P_k(x_1,\dots,x_a)=\sum_{(i_1,\dots,i_k)\in\{1,\dots,a\}^k} x_{i_1}\cdot x_{\min(i_1,i_2)}\cdot x_{\min(i_2,i_3)} \cdots x_{\min(i_{k-1},i_k)} \cdot x_{i_k}.
$$
Can you find a closed-form formula for this polynomial, i.e., find the coefficient of the term $x_{j_1}x_{j_2}\cdots x_{j_{k+1}}$ for any given $1\leq j_1\leq j_2\leq\cdots\leq j_{k+1}\leq a$? If this problem appeared somewhere earlier, a reference is more than welcome!

Comment: The $k=2$ case, for reference:

If $p < q$, then $i_1i_2 = pq$ or $qp$ both give rise to $x_p^2 x_q$, while if $p=q$ then $i_1i_2$ gives rise to $x_p^3$. Thus

$$P_2(x_1, \ldots, x_a) = 2\sum_{1 \leq p < q \leq a} x_p^2 x_q + \sum_{1 \leq p \leq a} x_p^3$$

This doesn't seem to meaningfully simplify. This feels related to counting linear extensions of posets to me, which is known to be hard.